# how remove "complete action using" window from my app when click on TextView ??

Tags: android, textview

When I click on TextView I get this window "complete action using" that I don't need it !!

So How I can remove or void this window in my app?

This is my code

```
TextView text1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.Arabapp);
ext1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try{
            Intent m = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            getString(R.string.ama_for_aou);
            startActivity(m);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            return;
    }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

> when I click on TextView I get this window "complete action using" that I don't need it !!

Yes, you do. You are asking to view something, without specifying what you want to view. This will cause every activity that responds to `ACTION_VIEW` to be shown in a chooser.

> so How I can remove or void this window in my app ??

Delete your `startActivity()` call. Or, use a better `Intent` with the `startActivity()` call.

Answer (score 1):

Thats because you are calling an Implicit Intent, which is causing this,

Check [this link out](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/471.html)

**Implicit Intents** have not specified a component; instead, they must include enough information for the system to determine which of the available components is best to run for that intent.

Hope you get my point